# UML Class Diagram - User and User Type

Tags: class, uml, class-diagram, tool-uml, erd

This is about User and User Type relationship.

I have two classes User and UserType
User has UserID, UserName, UserTypeID
UserType as : TypeID, TypeName

One user can have only one User Type (TypeID1/TypeID2/TypeID3)

What could be UML class diagram notation to represent this? is it association  or composition or aggregation?

This diagram has Car and car type as Association
http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/screenshots/80/uml2.png

This diagram has plugin and plugin type as composition 
http://indico-software.org/raw-attachment/wiki/Dev/Technical/PluginSystem/Plugin%20System%20class%20diagram.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this?
[image]

or like this
[image]

it dependents buddy, the first solution is useful when the user type does some functionality itself, in other word its a class(member), while the second solution is just useful when there is some constant about user types.

Answer (score 2):

In order to know how to choose between association, composition or aggregation, you just have to answer at these two questions.
1) One is a part of the other? Yes => composition or aggregation, No => Association.
2) if you "delete" the container does the contain still exist? Yes => aggregation, No => Composition.

So as I understood your model you  should model an association between User and UserType.
Another solution would be to model an attribute on User with UserType as type.